# Hide div tag / javascript from mobile phones?

Tags: javascript, html, hide

I would like to hide this div tag from mobile browsers only, is this possible?

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_floating_style addthis_32x32_style" style="left:50px;top:50px;">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_share"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_linkedin"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_share"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_stumbleupon"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-51f184b5319b19ad"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect of the user is on a handheld device like this:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}
```

Replace `//some code...` with the code you want to use to hide the div.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to hide dive because of screen size you can use css media queries and hide div for screens which less than some size